# Working with time intervals

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table(begin, end, typeid) with time intervals, something like this:

```
...
14:10:44    14:15:51  1
14:12:33    14:18:42  2
15:24:09    15:24:17  1
...
```

There is some rules: intervals with type id 2 intersepts with intervals of type 1. 
And after processing I get something like this:

```
...
14:10:44    14:18:42 <-- as a result of merging
15:24:09    15:24:17 
...
```

Is there exists any tehnics or methods to work with such data? May be there exists any usefull representation of intervals of time?

P.S. SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really hard to code up against data like yours. I have seen it a couple of times in real life situations. Here are 2 ideas.

```
declare @t table(low time, high time, type_id tinyint)

insert @t values('14:10:44','14:15:51', 1)
insert @t values('14:12:33','14:18:42', 2)
insert @t values('15:24:09','15:24:17', 1)

select low, coalesce(a.high, t.high) high 
from @t t 
cross apply (select min(high) high 
from @t t2 
where high > t.high and type_id = 2  
and not exists (select 1 from @t 
where t2.high between low and high and type_id = 2 and not 
(t2.high = high and t2.low = low))) a
where type_id = 1
```

Here is an alternative way. May even be better, depending on your data.

```
;with cte as 
(
select low low2, high, low 
from @t where type_id = 1 
union all
select cte.high, t.high, cte.low
from @t t 
join cte on cte.high > t.low 
and cte.high < t.high 
where t.type_id = 2
)
select low, max(high) high  from cte group by low
```

I am assuming that the low with type_id 1 is always the lowest in the set. I am also assuming there are no overlapping sets for rows with type_id 1 (and their subrows) since that would make no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly how I decide the problem... but I have about 9 defernt type ids and they have different behaveor - they can split other interval, merge with intervals of other types, intersepts and so on. So my stored proc now looks like ... m... Its looks very big :о). I even thought wouldn't it better represent an intervals as a sets of seconds and work with it how a sets of rows...

Comment: I have to see the new question with test data and expected outcome